# display variable value in UITextField by iOS, Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Data I need to displayed has been stored into a temp file.When I execute the application, NSLog can receive the data, but UITextField didn't respond. I don't know if I am using the correct syntax. And I am not sure why it doesn't work...

Update: I tried to assign a value to UItextField, but the UItextField doesn't display it neither

```
 -(void)readFilewin
{
// ....
NSString *pathsWin;
NSArray *pathsWin1= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
pathsWin = [[pathsWin1 objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arraycountwin.plist"];
NSArray *getfile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathsWin];

//NSArray *getfile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"arraycountwin.plist"];
//self.TotalWinTextField.text = [getfile objectAtIndex:0];

NSString * win = [[NSString alloc]init];
win = [getfile objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Win : %@", win);

self.TotalWinTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", win];
}
-(void)readFileLoss{...}
-(void)readFilestats
{
// ....
NSString *statspath;
NSArray *statspaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
statspath = [[statspaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arraystats.plist"];
NSArray *getfile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:statspath];

NSString * time = [[NSString alloc]init];
time = [getfile objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Time : %@", time);

NSString * time1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
time1 = [getfile objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Time1 : %@", time1);

self.textField1.text = time;    //broke here after update the viewDidLoad as @paul11 advise
self.textField2.text = time1;
}
```

Update for testing purpose to make sure the textfield is working, but it cannot even read the assigned value:
     - (void)readFilewin
    {

```
    self.TotalWinTextField.text = @"23"; //DONT WORK
}
```

Comment: when `readFilewin` is being called and have you checked the outlet?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it

Comment: @Asif Asif, if you are talking about the IBOutlet, then YES, I checked it.

Comment: I mean where have you placed [self readFilewin] call?

Comment: In -(void)viewDidLoad

Comment: How did you instantiate the view controller that contains this code?  Are you sure that the instance that is running this code is the instance that is on screen?  Add an NSLog into `viewDidLoad` and see how many times it is logged

Comment: try making the call from `viewDidAppear`, see if the text is set to textfield.

Comment: @Paulw11 the view container for this class is a in NavigationViewContainer. This class will be triggered when a player click a button on the main view. The NSLog can display the value of variable win. UITextField should display... are you suggesting me to put "NSLog(@"Win : %@", win);" inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, well put something in `viewDidLoad`.  There are three possibilities- `TotalWinTextField` is nil, you have multiple view controller instances and the one you are talking to is not the one that is onscreen or the constraints for your text field are putting it offscreen/making it too small or something.

Comment: @AsifAsif what else do i need to put into it? I put the [self readFilewin] into viewDidAppear... but cannot tell the different

Comment: @could you give me some instructions on how to check them? Sorry I am new to iOS

Comment: @baciyan `self.TotalWinTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", win ];` <-- does it make any difference?

Comment: You can check for the first case by setting a breakpoint in your method and inspecting the value of self.TotalWinTextField (It should be a small t for total by convention).  See how many NSLogs you get from the `viewDidLoad` or set a breakpoint and make sure it only triggers once and for the third case I normally set the background of the textview to bright green or something in IB so that I can verify that the text field is actually there and visible.

Comment: @AsifAsif it gave me error message when i put self.TotalWinTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", win ]; into viewDidAppear. I replace self.TotalWinTextField.text = win by this. but not different

Comment: @baciyan can you tell me about the error message?

Comment: @AsifAsif Use of undeclared identifier 'win'; did you mean 'sin? and Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'double (*)(double)'

Comment: @baciyan Sorry, I meant to put the statement within `readFilewin` method replacing `self.TotalWinTextField.text = win;`

Comment: @Paulw11 I check the IBOutlet, it is pointing to the right UITextField. This is how I declared it "@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TotalWinTextField;"

Comment: @Paulw11 I set a break point from -(void)readFilewin to the end of viewDidLoad... could you give me a detail instruction on how to do "ou can check for the first case by setting a breakpoint in your method and inspecting the value of self.TotalWinTextField (It should be a small t for total by convention).  See how many NSLogs you get from the viewDidLoad or set a breakpoint and make sure it only triggers once"

Comment: @AsifAsif oh okay. Np. I tried it. but it doesn't work. didn't display anything

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/

Comment: NSLog the text field pointer at the point where you attempt to set the text.  I'm betting it will log as `(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that outlet is created correctly
Secondly, check it is properly synthesized
thridly, make sure outlet is nonatomic

change ur viewDidLoad to this

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //win self.TotalWinTextField = 0; 
        //loss self.TotalLossTextField = 0; 
        //stats self.textField1 = 0; 
        self.textField2 = 0; 
        self.textField3 = 0; 
        [self readFilewin]; 
        [self readFilelose]; 
        [self readFilestats];
      }`

Comment: 1. the outlet should be created correctly. i declared the outlet in .h file as "@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TotalWinTextField;"

Comment: 2. I check the synthesize for the outlet and my declaration.. it is connected

Comment: 1. ensure one more thing that this textfield is connected to only one outlet 2. Try to remove and reconnect the outlet

Comment: I did. Each of them connect only one outlet.. And I also remove and reconnect the outlet...but no luck

Comment: now, remove the uitextfield and add new uitextfield and connect the outlet and try. Hope it vil help1

Comment: Show your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: do a full clean for build using Option+Shift+Command+K and then try, also try to change background color of the uitextfield and try to write something in it manually when ran in simulator and then  read the text just input into the uitextfield using another ibaction

Comment: @Paulw11 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //win
    self.TotalWinTextField = 0;
    //loss
    self.TotalLossTextField = 0;
    //stats
    self.textField1 = 0;
    self.textField2 = 0;
    self.textField3 = 0;
    
    [self readFilewin];
    [self readFilelose];
    [self readFilestats];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: plese write ur code after this line  // Do any additional setup after loading the view. [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: You are setting all of your text field properties to nil - I assume you wanted something like `self.TotalWinTextField.text=@"0"` etc

Comment: @ZAZ Thank you. I did. but that doesn't work.. I corrected my code in viewDidLoad as Paulw11 suggested... but now it gave me error...that I use NSnumber somewhere...but I couldn't find it. could you take a look on my update post to see if you see a NSnumber?

Comment: are u getting this err in viewdidload?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to reference `UITextField` in the storyboard with your property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *totalWinTextField;
```

that is easy you just need to select your `UITextField` in the storyboard holding down the key `control` and you drag it to your property. You can see when the property is referenced when in the left side has a circle filled.

I hope to be helpful.

Comment: I did. just checked it.

Comment: verify that self.totalWinTextField is initialized

Comment: yes I initialized it in viewDidLoad. and the NSLog can read the value, but UITextField cannot display.

Comment: Try call this method `[self readFilewin]` in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, this is your `viewDidLoad` -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {     
    //win     
    self.TotalWinTextField = 0;     
    //loss     
    self.TotalLossTextField = 0;     
    //stats 
    self.textField1 = 0;     
    self.textField2 = 0;     
    self.textField3 = 0;          
    [self readFilewin];     
    [self readFilelose];     
    [self readFilestats];
}
```

This is setting all of your IBOutlets to nil (0).

I presume that what you meant was -

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {     
        //win     
        self.TotalWinTextField.text = @"0";     
        //loss     
        self.TotalLossTextField.text = @"0";     
        //stats 
        self.textField1.text = @"0";     
        self.textField2.text = @"0";     
        self.textField3.text = @"0";          
        [self readFilewin];     
        [self readFilelose];     
        [self readFilestats];
    }
```

Comment: Do i need to give a initial value to them? If so, where should I put the initial value 0 ?

Comment: I have added the code to give an initial value to the **contents** of the text field as "0". The textfield properties themselves are initialised from Image Builder via the IBOutlet

Comment: now it gave me error that "2014-10-18 18:40:53.656 Pong1[4569:119442] -[__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e3
2014-10-18 18:40:53.659 Pong1[4569:119442] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000e3'
"

Comment: The breakpoint is at another method -(void)readFilestats; I have file path -(void)readFilestats{ file paths....;NSString * time = [[NSString alloc]init]; time = [getfile objectAtIndex:0]; NSLog(@"Time : %@", time); NSString * time1 = [[NSString alloc]init]; time1 = [getfile objectAtIndex:1]; NSLog(@"Time1 : %@", time1); self.textField1.text = [getfile objectAtIndex:0];self.textField2.text = [getfile objectAtIndex:1]; }

Comment: You have assigned an NSNumber somewhere where the object is supposed to be an NSString.

Comment: That code is alright if self.TotalTextField is indeed a UITextField, but the exception message indicates that it isn't - you have corrupted it somewhere else.  Search through your code and make sure you don't assign anything to `self.TotalTextField` - only `self.TotalTextField.text`